# Cannot access object Instance

Tags: c#

I have an object which has two properties.
I want to access to `Name` property, but cannot refer to `objA`.
What is wrong with this code?

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        Name = "";
        Age = 0;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    A objA = new A(){ Name = "AAA", Age = 19 };
    objA // Cannot Access objA instance
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're at class level. You can define variables and methods in that scope, but that's pretty much it. To interact with your objects and have some logic, you need to define a method.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    A objA = new A(){ Name = "AAA", Age = 19 };

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        var thing = objA.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I refer to objA in class fields level!.Thank you to Pierre-Luc Pineault. I'm sorry to ask basic question.I survay more.